# i have an error :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, router

`

```
const router =require('express').Router();
    let user =require('../models/user.model');


router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{
    user.find()
        .then(users=>res.json(users))enter code here
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error:'+err))

});

router.route('/add').post((req,res)=>{
    const username=req.body.username;

    const newUser=new user({
        username: username
    });
 newUser.save()
        .then(()=>res.json('user Added'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error:'+err));

});
module.exports=router;`
```

Comment: most likely means that `req.body` is undefined

Comment: Please try to post questions with some relevant details. Do not just post only your code. Try to follow these rules before asking questions in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This part shouldn't be there:  'enter code here'

Comment: please @jtate help me fixing my code i m going crazy buddy